# How do I raise a number to a power in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How can I calculate a number with an exponent in Elixir?

For example, 2<sup>3</sup> would return 8.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## `**/2`

As of Elixir 1.13, `**` is available.

```
> 2 ** 3 
8
```

Note: it returns a float if the exponent is less than 0.

[Documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#**/2)

Comment: I am not sure if it works, as I get an error -> (SyntaxError) iex:3:4: syntax error before: '*'

Comment: Hi @Borybar. Could you confirm what version of Elixir you're using? I just tried with the  1.13 release candidate (1.13.0-rc.0) and received the following:


    `>  elixir -v
    Elixir 1.13.0-rc.0 (5062a15) (compiled with Erlang/OTP 22)`

and iex console:
  
   `iex(1)> 2 ** 4` outputs `16`

Comment: I am using Elixir 1.12.2, so I guess an older version. However, as I see it's not working for you now also, so am I correct to believe that it's linked to a version?

Comment: That's unfortunately the case. It was added in the most recent version. [changelog](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.13/CHANGELOG.md#elixir). The other solutions on this page should suffice if you're on ~1.12.

Answer (score 89):

## Use the [Erlang :math module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/math.html)

```
:math.pow(2,3) #=> 8.0
```

If you want an integer:

```
:math.pow(2,3) |> round #=> 8
```

Answer (score 74):

Edit: given `**/2` exists now (see accepted answer), you should use it (or `Integer.pow/2` for `1.12`) instead of implementing one yourself, unless you're on elixir `< 1.12`.

Erlang's `:math.pow` has some limitations, for example it will not allow really high integer exponents:

```
iex(10)> :math.pow(2, 10000)
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
```

You can easily reimplement a fast algorithm for computing exponentials that will work with the arbitrarily large integers provided by the runtime:

```
defmodule Pow do
  require Integer

  def pow(_, 0), do: 1
  def pow(x, n) when Integer.is_odd(n), do: x * pow(x, n - 1)
  def pow(x, n) do
    result = pow(x, div(n, 2))
    result * result
  end
end

iex(9)> Pow.pow(2, 10000)
19950631168807583848837421626835850838234968318861924548520089498529438830...
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is a tail call optimized implementation of the power function:

```
def  pow(n, k), do: pow(n, k, 1)        
defp pow(_, 0, acc), do: acc
defp pow(n, k, acc), do: pow(n, k - 1, n * acc)
```

Comment: Very nice! Would be nice to replace `:math.pow`'s current implementation with an Erlang translation of this. https://github.com/erlang/otp

Answer (score 9):

## Integer.pow/2

As of v1.12, [Integer.pow/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12.0-rc.1/Integer.html#pow/2) is the way to do this.

Comment: For fractional bases/powers you still have to use `:math.pow/2`

Answer (score 6):

If the base is 2 and the power is an integer, you can do a left bitshift using the function [`Bitwise.bsl`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Bitwise.html#bsl/2). For example, 2<sup>3</sup> can be calculated with:

```
> Bitwise.bsl(1, 3)
8
```

Answer (score -3):

Tis works - it will be great when I learn enough to know exactly why it works - probably something to do with eval under the covers:

```
defmodule Example do
  require Integer

  def do_it(list) do
    list
    |> Enum.reject(&Integer.is_odd(&1))
    |> Enum.map(&(:math.pow(&1,3)))
  end

end
```